# What does "wrap" in np.pad actually do?

Tags: python, numpy, padding

When I am padding a numpy 2d array with `mode='wrap'`, the return from it make me confuse:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9, dtype=float).reshape(3, 3)
print(np.pad(a, [(2, 4), (1, 1)], mode='wrap'))
```

it return:

```
[[5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]
 [8. 6. 7. 8. 6.]
 [2. 0. 1. 2. 0.]
 [5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]
 [8. 6. 7. 8. 6.]
 [2. 0. 1. 2. 0.]
 [5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]
 [8. 6. 7. 8. 6.]
 [5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]]
```

the last row is`[[5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]]`, but I think(expect) it should be `[[2. 0. 1. 2. 0.]]`, that is it will repeat the given array again and again.
The fowolling code is I expect wrap should do:

```
def pad(array, pad_width, mode='wrap'):
    """pad_width definition is same as np.pad()"""
    size = array.shape[0] + pad_width[0][0] + pad_width[0][1], array.shape[1] + pad_width[1][0] + pad_width[1][1]
    if mode=='wrap':
        arr = np.empty(size, dtype=array.dtype)
        for i in range(size[0]):
            for j in range(size[1]):
                arr[i, j] = array[(i-pad_width[0][0])%array.shape[0], (j-pad_width[1][0])%array.shape[0]]
    else:
        print('Not define')
        return
    return arr

a = np.arange(9, dtype=float).reshape(3, 3)
print(pad(a, [(2, 4), (1, 1)], mode='wrap'))
```

return:

```
[[5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]
 [8. 6. 7. 8. 6.]
 [2. 0. 1. 2. 0.]
 [5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]
 [8. 6. 7. 8. 6.]
 [2. 0. 1. 2. 0.]
 [5. 3. 4. 5. 3.]
 [8. 6. 7. 8. 6.]
 [2. 0. 1. 2. 0.]]
```

Can someone explain what is "wrap" actually doing, thank you!

Edited(2nd):
Now, I have some feeling about what wrap did, it uses the definition of "wrap" and done by recursive to pad the array, but I still wonder what is usefulness of wrap padding?(I didn't make sense of this strange algorithm.)

Comment: So the difference lies in the source for that 4th pad row.  Should it be the first row of the **original** array, or the first row of the latest iteration.  It looks like the column padding is performed using the row-padded array as source.

Comment: @hpaulj I have check the source code erlier, It work just like you mentioned, but I still wonder what is usefulness of wrap padding, it seems stange for me, because since pading_width is lager we can't even find the rule(
numbers of sequence) in padding.

Comment: Ultimately `np.pad` is just a convenience function.  It isn't fast, and doesn't cover all cases that users might want.  I haven't had a need to use `wrap`, but I can imagine using it to handle a 'periodic' array.  The action is easiest to visualize when the padding is small relative to the original array.  But a general purpose function has to handle large pads as well - in one way or other.

Comment: @Patrickliu, I agree that your version is probably what most folks would expect `mode='wrap'` to do.  Could you create an [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) about this in the [numpy github repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy)? Your unexpected result and your expected behavior would be useful to include in the issue.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser I have created an issue on numpy([#22464](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22464)), but this is my first time create an issue on github, I'm wonder it won't be detailed enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the definition of `wrap` mode :

> 'wrap'
> Pads with the wrap of the vector along the axis.
> The first values are used to pad the end and the
> end values are used to pad the beginning.

And here's the code in `pad` method :

```py
@array_function_dispatch(_pad_dispatcher, module='numpy')
def pad(array, pad_width, mode='constant', **kwargs):

    array = np.asarray(array)
    pad_width = np.asarray(pad_width)

    if not pad_width.dtype.kind == 'i':
        raise TypeError('`pad_width` must be of integral type.')

    # Broadcast to shape (array.ndim, 2)
    pad_width = _as_pairs(pad_width, array.ndim, as_index=True)

    if callable(mode):
        # Old behavior: Use user-supplied function with np.apply_along_axis
        function = mode
        # Create a new zero padded array
        padded, _ = _pad_simple(array, pad_width, fill_value=0)
        # And apply along each axis

        for axis in range(padded.ndim):
            # Iterate using ndindex as in apply_along_axis, but assuming that
            # function operates inplace on the padded array.

            # view with the iteration axis at the end
            view = np.moveaxis(padded, axis, -1)

            # compute indices for the iteration axes, and append a trailing
            # ellipsis to prevent 0d arrays decaying to scalars (gh-8642)
            inds = ndindex(view.shape[:-1])
            inds = (ind + (Ellipsis,) for ind in inds)
            for ind in inds:
                function(view[ind], pad_width[axis], axis, kwargs)

        return padded

    # Make sure that no unsupported keywords were passed for the current mode
    allowed_kwargs = {
        'empty': [], 'edge': [], 'wrap': [],
        'constant': ['constant_values'],
        'linear_ramp': ['end_values'],
        'maximum': ['stat_length'],
        'mean': ['stat_length'],
        'median': ['stat_length'],
        'minimum': ['stat_length'],
        'reflect': ['reflect_type'],
        'symmetric': ['reflect_type'],
    }
    try:
        unsupported_kwargs = set(kwargs) - set(allowed_kwargs[mode])
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("mode '{}' is not supported".format(mode)) from None
    if unsupported_kwargs:
        raise ValueError("unsupported keyword arguments for mode '{}': {}"
                         .format(mode, unsupported_kwargs))

    stat_functions = {"maximum": np.amax, "minimum": np.amin,
                      "mean": np.mean, "median": np.median}

    # Create array with final shape and original values
    # (padded area is undefined)
    padded, original_area_slice = _pad_simple(array, pad_width)
    # And prepare iteration over all dimensions
    # (zipping may be more readable than using enumerate)
    axes = range(padded.ndim)

#All the other modes...

 elif mode == "wrap":
        for axis, (left_index, right_index) in zip(axes, pad_width):
            roi = _view_roi(padded, original_area_slice, axis)
            while left_index > 0 or right_index > 0:
                # Iteratively pad until dimension is filled with wrapped
                # values. This is necessary if the pad area is larger than
                # the length of the original values in the current dimension.
                left_index, right_index = _set_wrap_both(
                    roi, axis, (left_index, right_index))

    return padded
```

Now you can see the difference with what you assume it was doing and what it's really doing

You can find those information in the [Numpy GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy). The code for `pad` is in the file `arraypad.py` located at `numpy/numpy/lib/arraypad.py`

Comment: It seems like the core of wrap is in `_set_wrap_both()` function.Now, I have some feeling about what wrap did, it uses the definition of "wrap" and done by recursive to pad the array, but I still wonder what is usefulness of wrap padding?(I didn't make sense of this strange algorithm.)